# MapStates in every component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

In my current application I am using Vue.js, Vuex and vue-router.

On every component I load the states needed for that component:
Always, on every component: *user, company* is loaded and then the specific states needed for that component.

If the state is null/unset I run dispatch it's action to set it.

I am concerned however that doing so is bad practice and will influence my applications performance badly?

```
computed:{
...mapState({
  company:state => state.companies.active,
  user:state => state.users.user,
  xComponentSpecific: state => state.survey.active
}),
```

},

- Is this a good way to do it?
- Is mapGetters the recommended approach?
- Should I pass down company and user in props between parents/childs?

I have read the documentation however I don't think it states very clearly each senario's benifits/disadvantages.

Comment: If you are loading same state in every component. consider mixins..

Comment: getters are like computed properties for Vuex.. to get a derived state based on your state..